# Get the list of methods of a class

Tags: c++

Is there a way to create a list (e.g. an array) of pointers to each method of a C++ class?

Something like `Type.GetMethods()` in the .NET framework, but using only standard C++.

Comment: Not unless you do it by hand. And that's a scary thing to need. Why?

Comment: @Gman: +1 for "scary thing to need"

Comment: @GManNickG Why wouldn't it be possible to generate the list of methods of a C++ class by generating a parse tree of the class?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: For the compiler, sure. Not for the user of the language.

Comment: Facing the same problem but.. if it had, it were infinite...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No this is not possible in a general way.  C++ does not have the same metadata infrastructure that .Net posses.

Could you provide us with a scenario where you want to use this information?  There may be a better approach you can use with C++

Comment: By now it was just out of curiosity. I mean, yesterday I was thinking about some sort of library to handle JSON data, but today I can't remember why I thought about this approach -_- . Still the question remained, so I asked.

Comment: it's a good illustration of how different the languages are even if the syntax is similar-looking. The mentality of how to solve problems is entirely different between the two languages.

Comment: 7.5yrs late, but I have this scenario: A class `TestFoobar` contains a bunch of static methods `void test_* (void)` (these are unit tests for the class `Foobar`). In some other languages, I could just enumerate all of these and execute those which match the pattern; this ensures all methods are really called. In C++ I believe this is not possible, but I searched for an answer nonetheless -- which is why I ended up here ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way.

In fact, even at the object code level, a static class member function cannot be distinguished from a stand-alone function, nor a class instance function from a stand-alone function passing a pointer to an object.

If you know your compilers name-mangling scheme, and had access to the pre-linked object code, you might be able to decode it, but that's a lot of work for iffy results.

Answer (score 2):

Make a copy of the .h file and hack away with it in an editor.

No, there's no way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the type information using [typeid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeid) but not the method information.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to do this, chapter 8 of *Advanced C++ Programming Styles and Idioms* by James Coplien (probably long-since out of print, but I hear Neil would be willing to sell his copy cheaply) covers programming with "exemplars" in C++. Make not mistake, the capability doesn't come for  free, but it can/does provide metaclass-like capabilities in C++.

Offhand, I don't remember his building the particular capability you're looking for into one of his classes, but it's been a long time since I read that book carefully at all either. It's always *possible* that it couldn't be done at all, but I think it would work, if you can live with the other limitations of what he discloses.

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I use special macros for class members declaration and definition, then 
I can get the list of class members. For example:

Class declaration:

```
#define DECLARE_MODULE_FUNCTION( function_name ) \
JsonObject function_name( JsonObject value );

#define DEFINE_MODULE_FUNCTION( function_name ) \
static ModuleFunctionAdder< LotteryOddsModule > \
__LINE__##function_name( L ## #function_name , &LotteryOddsModule::function_name );    \
JsonObject LotteryOddsModule::function_name( JsonObject value )

template< typename T >
class ModuleFunctionAdder;

class LotteryOddsModule
{
public:
    typedef JsonObject ( LotteryOddsModule::*ModuleFunction )( JsonObject );

    JsonValue Invoke( JsonValue json_value );

    DECLARE_MODULE_FUNCTION( GenerateK1AndK2 );

private:
    friend class ModuleFunctionAdder< LotteryOddsModule >;
    static std::map< WString , ModuleFunction > _module_functions;
};

template<>
class ModuleFunctionAdder< LotteryOddsModule >
{
public:
    ModuleFunctionAdder( WString func_name , LotteryOddsModule::ModuleFunction func )
    {
        LotteryOddsModule::_module_functions[ func_name ] = func;
    }
};
```

Class definition:

```
JsonValue LotteryOddsModule::Invoke( JsonValue json_value )
{
    return ( this->*_module_functions[ L"GenerateK1AndK2" ] ) ( json_value.get_obj() );
}

DEFINE_MODULE_FUNCTION( GenerateK1AndK2 )
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no meta classes in C++ only objects and classes, hence no reflection could not be involved, so the answer is no.

Comment: Meta classes and reflection are orthogonal, the implication you're suggesting is invalid.