# How can I see all functions of a class?

Tags: c++, default-constructor, symbol-table

Mainly I want to see compiler-generated functions (default constructor, copy constructor, assignment-operator, move-assignment, destructor).
Just want to see which functions compiler generated for me.

I assumed I could see this in the symbol table but I'm having trouble spotting them in the symbol table with name mangling. I can see other functions I defined but I don't know how I can find the constructors, etc.

Is there a better way to see which functions are associated with a class?

Comment: I hope this similar thread might help you get close,[**link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526546/get-the-list-of-methods-of-a-class)

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with your idea:

The compiler will *implicitly declare* special functions when allowed.
But it will only *implicitly define* them, iff they are ODR-used.

Also, that use might have been inlined, so there might not be a symbol to find.

Thus, the only fail-safe way to find out which functions the compiler will generate on-demand is trying to use them.
Though just knowing the rules and checking manually should be sufficient, they are easy enough.

Comment: Thank you. Seems there really isn't a good way to check this. Maybe looking at the disassembly? See if there is a JUMP call somewhere?

Comment: @madu: The point is that those implicit special functions might not exist even though the compiler can generate them, either because they were never needed, or because every use was inlined, so there is nothing left to find.

Comment: Thank you. I understand there are different cases. What I wanted to see, at minimum, was to have an empty class, in this case there will be no functions generated. But if I add a virtual function, then compiler will put a constructor to create the vtable (for example). I wanted to see this case where compiler generated the const. for me. But as you said, it could be inline-ed.