# Is there a way to include all objects in a C++ header with Boost.Python?

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have the following code:

```
#include "boost_facade.h"

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE (libdtlinux) {
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<DtSearch>("DtSearch")
            .def("DoSearch", &DtSearch::DoSearch)
            .def("CreateIndex", &DtSearch::CreateIndex);
}
```

What I would like to do is have Boost automatically add the `class DtSearch` and all sub methods without defining them one by one in the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`.

Is there a way to include all object in the header file, or will I need to just specify them as I'm doing now?

**Update**

SWIG has functionality that I'm looking for, however I need to use Boost.Python. Here is the swig example:

```
%module example
 %{
 /* Includes the header in the wrapper code */
 #include "header.h"
 %}

 /* Parse the header file to generate wrappers */
 %include "header.h"
```

Reference: http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html under **SWIG for the truly lazy**

Comment: I would imagine not (or under restricted circumstances maybe) based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526546/get-the-list-of-methods-of-a-class).

Comment: @RobertPrévost I do agree that C++ does not work like this, however I've updated my question with a reference to SWIG. If it doesn't work, I'm totally fine with that. I just didn't know if Boost supported this.

Comment: Just a thought - from what I've seen (although I haven't tried myself), it's relatively simple to analyze C++ code with libclang. Perhaps you could use that to build a code generator that would generate Boost.Python wrappers?